How to implement an range selector input using Excel Javascript API?
I have an Excel Add-In that opens a taskpane and, using Excel Javascript API, displays a form that the user fills in. In that form, I need to include an input where the user should be able to select a cell/range. In other words, the same behaviour of this Excel component:

I have a React component with similar Look&Feel (a common <input type="text"> with a <div onClick="..."> inside) , but I can't find the way to switch focus from taskpane to Excel without using the mouse as Excel does with this range selector component in the image.
Is there a built-in component or a Javascript API function to achieve this behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Please clarify what component this is. I don't recognize it. Also, what is "L&F"?

Clarified. Done

Sorry, but I still don't know what "this Excel component" refers to.

In Excel, for example when you insert a Chart, you have a control (like the one in the image) that allows you to select a range when you click on the icon. When you develop a Web Add-In using Excel JS API, you have to use HTML  to replicate that behavior. The problem is that you can't change focus from the taskpane to the spreadsheet and capture the selection event

As far as I know there is no way to activate the grid from the office-js code running in the task-pane. You could fake that behavior by adding key listeners to the html page that respond to the cursor direction keys (changing the cell selection) and also properly responds to whether or not the shift key is down.
